# NP vs QuasiP and W[1] vs FPT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fixed-parameter-tractable

If $F[1]=WPT$ then ETH is false. The converse is unknown (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis#Structural_complexity).

How about the strong assumption of $NP\subseteq QuasiP$? Would $F[1]=WPT$ hold?